# R merged dataset count time between first purchase and first visit

Tags: r, distinct, difference

I have 2 large datasets that I merged together. One dataset contains info on purchases made by customers, the other dataset contains info on visits made in the shop by the same customers.

When I merged the data I did it by customer_id, so now I have a merged dataset that looks like this:

```
#  customer_no       visit date    purchase date
#2       10          20-10-2014         NA 
#3       10              NA         12-01-2013
#4       10          17-06-2011         NA 
#5       10              NA         18-02-2012
#8       30          22-12-2013         NA 
#9       30          14-07-2012         NA
```

I would like to generate a new variable that gives me the days of difference between FIRST visit and FIRST purchase. So, R should be able to identify which date is the first in the visits column for each unique customer_no, identify which date is first in the purchase column for the same customer_no and then calculate the difference.

Presumably the new column will be all NA and one value per customer.

Thanks!!

So, in the case of customer no.10 she made a first visit on 17-06-2011 but she made her first purchase on 18-02-2012 -> 246 days. I would like to know the average of this on all customers in the merged dataset.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you may have an erroneous column name in there

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(customer_no) %>% 
  summarize(diff = min(as.numeric(as.Date(purchase_date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")), na.rm=T) - 
                   min(as.numeric(as.Date(visit_date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")), na.rm=T))
```

Comment: Mmm it's not working, or I am doing smth wrong. This is the message I get:

    n min(as.numeric(as.Date(structure(c(1191L, NA, NA, NA,  ... :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

An alternative would be to create a new column (new variable) that for each customer it gives me the difference between first visit and first purchase. As for each customer I have multiple rows (all the visits and all the purchases), in that new columns I would have one cell with the no. of days between first visit and first purchase and all others would have NA.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not spectacularly elegant, but as far as I understand your request it outputs the dataframe you would like to see. The `for` loop in the example generates a warning because customer `30` has no `purchase_date`, then we are trying to get the difference between a date and an `NA`, but that's OK since the result is another `NA`.

```
df <- data.frame(customer_no = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 30, 30),
                 visit_date = c("20-10-2014", NA, "17-06-2011", NA, "22-12-2013", "14-07-2012"),
                 purchase_date = c(NA, "12-01-2013", NA, "18-02-2012", NA, NA))

df$diff <- rep(NA, nrow(df)) 


customers <- unique(df$customer_no)
diff_first_visit_purchase <- data.frame()

for (customer in customers) {
  sub.df <- subset(df, customer_no == customer)
  first_visit <- min(as.Date(sub.df$visit_date, format="%d-%m-%Y"), na.rm=TRUE)
  first_purchase <- min(as.Date(sub.df$purchase_date, format="%d-%m-%Y"), na.rm=TRUE)
  temp.df <- data.frame(customer_no = customer,
                        visit_date = NA,
                        purchase_date = NA,
                        diff = as.integer(first_purchase - first_visit))
  diff_first_visit_purchase <- rbind(diff_first_visit_purchase, temp.df)

}


final.df <- rbind(df, diff_first_visit_purchase)
final.df <- final.df[order(final.df$customer_no),]

final.df
#  customer_no visit_date purchase_date diff
#1          10 20-10-2014          <NA>   NA
#2          10       <NA>    12-01-2013   NA
#3          10 17-06-2011          <NA>   NA
#4          10       <NA>    18-02-2012   NA
#7          10       <NA>          <NA>  246
#5          30 22-12-2013          <NA>   NA
#6          30 14-07-2012          <NA>   NA
#8          30       <NA>          <NA>   NA

mean(final.df$diff, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 246
```